# cgminer on OSX: Cannot open executable file

Tags: mac, litecoin, cgminer

I'm trying to use litecoin on OSX with NVidia or CPU mining, and [downloaded the binary from here](http://ck.kolivas.org/apps/cgminer/)

The specific binary I extracted was `cgminer-2.10.5-x86_64-built.tar.bz2`.  I extracted it and used terminal to CD into the extracted directory.

There is a file there that has execute permissions on it ( `ls -lag` )

```
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 staff  382808 Feb  7 01:50 cgminer
```

If I double click on, or run the app cgminer OSX says: `cannot execute binary file`.

I verified that my security settings are set to run "unsigned programs from any author" but I don't think that matters in OSX.

How do I run cgminer on OSX?

---

```
server:cgminer-2.10.5-x86_64-built username$ od cgminer | head
0000000    042577  043114  000402  000001  000000  000000  000000  000000
0000020    000002  000076  000001  000000  072500  000100  000000  000000
0000040    000100  000000  000000  000000  150130  000005  000000  000000
0000060    000000  000000  000100  000070  000011  000100  000034  000033
0000100    000006  000000  000005  000000  000100  000000  000000  000000
0000120    000100  000100  000000  000000  000100  000100  000000  000000
0000140    000770  000000  000000  000000  000770  000000  000000  000000
0000160    000010  000000  000000  000000  000003  000000  000004  000000
0000200    001070  000000  000000  000000  001070  000100  000000  000000
0000220    001070  000100  000000  000000  000034  000000  000000  000000
```

Comment: Did you try `tar xvf <filename>`, then run the file inside?

Comment: @NickODell I just re-tried the process using that command. Same error

Comment: No, I mean run the file that the tar command just unpacked.

Comment: @NickODell I clarified in the question just now.

Comment: Can you try `od cgminer | head`?

Comment: @NickODell - I updated the question...

Comment: Hmmm, are you on a 32 bit system?

Comment: My hardware is x64 (Mac Retina).  I don't think OSX 10.8.2 comes in x32 bit flavor. - @NickODell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have downloaded the linux version of cgminer, that's not going to run on OS X.

I don't think there is a ready built binary for cgminer on OS X.